# How to calculate time without finger pressing in the screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, timer

I would like to count the time since i last pressed the screen (or button) in an iPod Touch 4g project. 
Is the only way to do this, trigger a timer when i stop pressing the button?
thks

(ps: i don't write code in this question, cause this is a generic question inside iOS, but if anyone can help me with code, i would be thankful).

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously been a long time since you asked this question, but in case anyone else is looking for a potential solution, try using the code I created over on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994884/1007725

Essentially you needed to look up how to use IDLE time.

Answer (score -1):

It's exactly like you suggested..

```
Pseudo code:

variable currentTime  // declared in header or something like that

initMethod {
    currentTime = "get current time from timer"
}

touchMethod {
    print: "get current time from timer" - currentTime
    currentTime = "get current time from timer"
}
```

Edit: for clarity.

Comment: Confusing reply :-/, I have the same problem and I (but I think everyone) can't understand with this.

Comment: Is it easier to understand now?