# How to present UIAlertView from appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, view

I m trying to display a UIAlertView from the appDelegate in 
        didReceiveRemoteNotification
when the app receive a push notification.

I ve this error :

```
  Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x14c5494c0> on <UINavigationController:
  0x14c60ce00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

here is my code :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: NSDictionary) {

    var contentPush: NSDictionary = userInfo.objectForKey("aps") as NSDictionary

    var message = contentPush.objectForKey("alert") as String



    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default Style", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
                    // ...
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in

        let photoPushedVc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CommentTableViewController") as CommentTableViewController

        println("the fetched post is \(post)")

        photoPushedVc.post = post

        let activeVc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

        activeVc?.presentViewController(photoPushedVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   alertController.addAction(OKAction)

   let activeVc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController


   activeVc?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have it display from the root view controller?

Comment: as you can see in my code, i m trying to dysplay it from the active VC using let activeVc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

Comment: Note that i have a tabBarController in my app.

Comment: Why would you think a "rootViewController" is necessarily the "active VC"?

Comment: i was thinking that the .keyWindow? gives the "active VC". If not how would you get it ?

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes i do. Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009646/current-view-controller-from-appdelegate but can't translate in swift.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68306/discussion-between-jmcastel-and-lyndsey-scott).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok i finally got it, you need to find the active VC using this before trying to present your alertController :

```
let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as UINavigationController
let activeViewCont = navigationController.visibleViewController
activeViewCont.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You should also check that activeVC is not already presenting, otherwise it won't works. By checking if activeViewCont.presentedViewController return nil

Answer (score 20):

To generate **AlertController** Dialog Box from **AppDelegate** using **Objective-C**,

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Hello World!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:ok];
```

**Type 1**

```
UIWindow *alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
[alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Type 2**

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
while (topController.presentedViewController) {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}
[topController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Both are **tested** and working fine.

Comment: sometimes will work, but Pavel's answer is better solution.

Comment: Type 1 worked for any case. Type 2 may not work for some of devices.

Answer (score 13):

Here is mine Swift 3.0 example

```
func showTopLevelAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController (title: "title", message: "message.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "First", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(firstAction)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Отмена", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Hope it helps to someone

Comment: This looks like a good one. Just one reminder: Don't forget to do all of this inside the main thread, otherwise it will crash at `alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()`.

Comment: How will the `UIWindow` be deallocated?

Comment: @meaning-matters it will be deallocated as you close UIAlertController dialog

Answer (score 6):

If you need the same in Objective-c

```
UIAlertController *alertvc = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title..!!" message:@"Hey! Alert body come here." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

}];

[alertvc addAction:actionOk];
```

1. If you have navigation based app:

   ```
   UINavigationController *nvc = (UINavigationController *)[[application windows] objectAtIndex:0].rootViewController;
   UIViewController *vc = nvc.visibleViewController;
   [vc presentViewController:alertvc animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
2. If you have single view based app:

   ```
   UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
   [vc presentViewController:alertvc animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

Comment: How do you do this with a single view app (not a navigation controller based app).

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Please check my second answer. (Answer updated.)

Answer (score 5):

how i did it

```
func showAlertAppDelegate(title : String,message : String,buttonTitle : String,window: UIWindow){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Use Example

`self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: "Alert",message: "Opened From AppDelegate",buttonTitle: "ok",window: self.window!);`

[Download Example With Source Code](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/ios-swift-open-uialertview-dialog-from-appdelegate-uiapplicationdelegate/)

Answer (score 1):

I use an UIViewController extension to get the current visible view controller (see: [How to get visible viewController from app delegate when using storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882078/how-to-get-visible-viewcontroller-from-app-delegate-when-using-storyboard)).

and then present the alert controller:

```
let visibleVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.visibleViewController
visibleVC!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

To show alert on top controller from app delegate

```
var topController : UIViewController = (application.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!

    while ((topController.presentedViewController) != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }

    //showAlertInViewController func is in UIAlertController Extension
    UIAlertController.showAlertInViewController(topController, withMessage: messageString, title: titleString)
```

Add extension in UIAlertController

```
    static func showAlertInViewController(viewController: UIViewController?, withMessage message: String, title: String) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: ""), style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Handle Ok logic here")

        // Let the alert simply dismiss for now
    }))

    viewController?.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```