# Display UIAlertController over UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I have a `UIWindow` nested above all of my navigation controllers (it's a swipeable, draggable mini video player). I'm initializing it like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let player = CustomWindowClass(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    var window: UIWindow? {
        set {

        }
        get {

            return player
        }
    }
}
```

Now that `player` has a button on it's page that should prompt a `UIAlertController`. My problem is that I can't `presentViewController:` directly from the `UIWindow`. I can use:

```
let rootView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
rootView?.presentViewController(theAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

..but it appears behind my `UIWindow`. I've been searching all day for how I can safely display the `UIAlertController` above my `UIWindow`, but have been empty-handed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the size of the returned array of `windows` from `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows`?

I'm guessing that it will be 2, and the second one in the array will be your new window.  Try investigating each `window` in the returned array, and try presenting the `UIAlertViewController` on each of those to see if it has the desired effect.

eg, if there are two `windows` returned:

```
let controller = application.windows[1].rootViewController as UIViewController
controller.presentViewController(theAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Reference: [How to present UIAlertView from appDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807104/how-to-present-uialertview-from-appdelegate)

Comment: Thanks, this worked more or less. I also have to reset the `UIWindow.windowLevel` to make it work