# Get current ViewController in external method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a external function to check if user is already logged into Firebase.

My code is working, but in trying to ensure that current VC is dismissing in the end, I get an error.

My question is: How can i get the current VC or how can i use self. to reference the current VC that function is called?

```
class Helper{

static func checkIfLogged()  {

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = controller

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) **** ERROR IS HERE ***

    }

}

}
```

Comment: You want to avoid passing the current view controller to the `checkIfLogged()` method? In that case see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009646/current-view-controller-from-appdelegate

Comment: I want to pass, but how can i instantiate the current view controller in this function?

Comment: What about : `static func checkIfLogged(vc: UIViewController)  {`? Then `vc.dismiss(`...

Comment: Great. That was exactly was i looking for. Than is just i call Helper.checkIfLogged(vc: self), right?

Comment: If the caller is always the current view controller, yes. You should place this method inside an extension of `UIViewController` in that case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
extension UIApplication{
class func getPresentedViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    var presentViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while let pVC = presentViewController?.presentedViewController
    {
        presentViewController = pVC
    }

    return presentViewController
  }
}
```

just add this extension and call : UIApplication. getPresentedViewController()