# iOS:Convert ObjC code to C#, How to know the time app has been idle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am new to iOS development, I am using monotouch for developing the iOS apps, i want to know the time since the app was idle, i got the ObjC code but am unable to convert it into c#. 
Here is the code:

```c
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    // Only want to reset the timer on a Began touch or an Ended touch, to reduce the number of timer resets.
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0) {
        // allTouches count only ever seems to be 1, so anyObject works here.
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
            [self resetIdleTimer];
    }
}

- (void)resetIdleTimer {
    if (idleTimer) {
        [idleTimer invalidate];
        [idleTimer release];
    }

    idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxIdleTime target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
}

 - (void)idleTimerExceeded {
    NSLog(@"idle time exceeded");
}
```

Can anyone help me in converting this to c#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's certainly better way to achieve this, but let's do a almost line to line translation fo this `Obj-C` code to `Xamarin.iOS` `C#`:

`sendEvent` is a method of `UIApplication`. It's very uncommon to subclass it, see **Subclassing notes** on [UIApplication class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Once you subclassed it, you have to instruct the runtime to use it, that's done in the `Main` method, normally found in `Main.cs`. Here's what the modified `Main.cs` looks like now.

```cs
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main (args, "MyApplication", "AppDelegate");
    }
}

[Register ("MyApplication")]
public class MyApplication : UIApplication
{

}
```

Notice the `Register` attribute on the class, used as second argument of `UIApplication.Main`.

Now, let's translate your code for real:

```cs
[Register ("MyApplication")]
public class MyApplication : UIApplication
{
    public override void SendEvent (UIEvent uievent)
    {
        base.SendEvent (uievent);
        var allTouches = uievent.AllTouches;
        if (allTouches.Count > 0) {
            var phase = ((UITouch)allTouches.AnyObject).Phase;
            if (phase == UITouchPhase.Began || phase == UITouchPhase.Ended)
                ResetIdleTimer ();
        }
    }

    NSTimer idleTimer;
    void ResetIdleTimer ()
    {
        if (idleTimer != null) {
            idleTimer.Invalidate ();
            idleTimer.Release ();
        }

        idleTimer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (TimeSpan.FromHours (1), TimerExceeded);
    }

    void TimerExceeded ()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine ("idle time exceeded");
    }
}
```

I replaced `maxIdleTime` by `TimeSpan.FromHours (1)`. Otherwise, you'll have the same behaviour as the Obj-C one, including bugs if any (it looks ok though).

Comment: Thanks, Stephane for doing this great workaround for me its working like a charm, I also got some idea from your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331680/session-maintenance-in-monotouch which i got today.

Comment: haha, I was quite sure I answered something that required overriding UIApplication already !

Comment: Awesome. Just found that it should be idleTimer.Dispose(); instead of "release" and TimerExceeded(NSTimer obj).