# How to calculate App Idle Time in MVVMCross Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing iOS Universal Application in Xamarin.iOS using MVVMCross. I want to calculate App Idle time I found the following useful help

[iOS:Convert ObjC code to C#, How to know the time app has been idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928361/iosconvert-objc-code-to-c-how-to-know-the-time-app-has-been-idle)

But there is an issue when i try to use this with MVVMCross which is that 
AppDelegate.cs in MvvmCross is inherited from MvxApplicationDelegate.cs

I am unable to override the following event in AppDelegate because it is not overriding UIApplication

```
public override void SendEvent (UIEvent uievent)
    {
        base.SendEvent (uievent);
        var allTouches = uievent.AllTouches;
        if (allTouches.Count > 0) {
            var phase = ((UITouch)allTouches.AnyObject).Phase;
            if (phase == UITouchPhase.Began || phase == UITouchPhase.Ended)
                ResetIdleTimer ();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close to the answer.

In  a default MvvMCross project, there is a **Main.cs**, that contains a `Application` class.

You just have to replace the null in following line with your UIApplication's child class name

```
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

e.g If your class name is MyApplication which is inherited from UIApplication then it should be like

```
UIApplication.Main(args, "MyApplication", "AppDelegate");
```

and add a class `MyApplication`

```
[Register("MyApplication")]
public class MyApplication : UIApplication
{
    public override void SendEvent(UIEvent uievent)
    {
        base.SendEvent(uievent);
        var allTouches = uievent.AllTouches;
        if (allTouches.Count > 0)
        {
            var phase = ((UITouch)allTouches.AnyObject).Phase;
            if (phase == UITouchPhase.Began || phase == UITouchPhase.Ended)
                ResetIdleTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so where we write the FinishLaunching code of mvvmcross AppDelegateClass in which we set our App Start

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)

Comment: You don't change it. This logic stays where it is - in the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Yes you seems right :) sorry for negative answer. Let me check it