# Global Touch Event in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event

my question is related to touch event which is Global in app

This is my scenario,

I Have an App with 15 screens, When first screen launches the timer starts, User goes from one screen to another screen randomly, In that case i need to reset the timer, If timer reaches to (say 120 seconds ) i have to destroy the current user session and logout n starts from first screen.

The implementation code for `startLogoutTimer` `resetLogoutTimer` and `stopLogoutTimer` is in AppDelegate class, if User navigates to any screen and touches the screen, i need to execute the methods of  startLogoutTimer, resetLogoutTimer and stopLogoutTimer based on action but without message call to AppDelegate from every class (Screen/ViewController).

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My above Problem is Solved.
I added the below code into AppDelegate class

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resetLogoutTimer) name:UITouchPhaseBegan object:nil];
```

Now where ever I touch on screen, my timer restarts.

Comment: does not compile, UITouchPhaseBegan is an enum, not a NSString

Answer (score 0):

Create category for UIView and handle touches in it.

```
@implementation UIView (Touch)

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [((Appdelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) resetLogoutTimer];

}
```

Or you cand do it the same with swizzling

Comment: Thank you, the logic works correct, but i have minor problem, when I use catagory the method `touchedEnded` calls for three times instead of one, Does you have any other way which is related to `UIWindow`, because every App has only one **Window**, which I can use for handling the Touch Event.

Answer (score 0):

Hi below two links solved my problem

[iOS perform action after period of inactivity (no user interaction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085188/ios-perform-action-after-period-of-inactivity-no-user-interaction)

[Timing Out An Application Due To Inactivity](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/09/19/timing-out-an-application-due-to-inactivity/)